# How to use JSTL in tomcat 7?

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I am a beginner in JSP and Servlets developing. I want to develop a small application that uses JSTL. But I don`t know  how to use JSTL. Can any one tell me how to use JSTL without any IDE? Where can I find step by step instructions? 
because I suffer from the following error.

```
The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this
```

Comment: Why do you not want to use an IDE?

Comment: and have you tried googling it?

Comment: I used this when I first learned JSTL: http://www.java-tips.org/java-tutorials/tutorials/introduction-to-jstl-using-netbeans.html

Comment: because using IDE is not allowed to me.. and I also googling but cant find required stuff..

Comment: Put your mouse on top of `[jstl]` tag which you placed on the question until a black box shows up and then click therein the *info* link.

Comment: Hummm... can you to use Ant or Maven from command line?

Answer (score 0):

JSTL just provides an effective(cleaner and more readable) way to embed logic within a JSP page without using embedded Java code directly. Its not mandatory to use IDE to use JSTL.
Here the brief about JSTL

```
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_standard_tag_library.htm
```

Though you will find ample tutorial for JSTL on Google.